# Display all documents belonging to the currently log in user

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

All documents have a field containing the userId of the user who created the document.

I trying to make a query which shows all documents containing the currently log in users, userId. But my problem is that the userId is undefined.

Component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from './../core/auth.service';
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreDocument, AngularFirestoreCollection } from 'angularfire2/firestore';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';

export interface Restaurants { address: string; img: string; name: string; owernId: string; tag: string[]; }
export interface RestaurantsId extends Restaurants { id: string; }

interface User {
  uid: string;
  email: string;
  photoURL?: string;
  displayName?: string;
  favoriteColor?: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-personal-notes',
  templateUrl: './personal-notes.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./personal-notes.component.css']
})

export class PersonalNotesComponent implements OnInit {
  userId;
  private restaurantsCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Restaurants>;
  restaurants: Observable<RestaurantsId[]>;

  constructor(public auth: AuthService, private afs: AngularFirestore, private afAuth: AngularFireAuth) {

    // Get currentUser Id
    this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(user => {
      if (user) { this.userId = user.uid; }
      console.log(this.userId);
    });

    // Query all restauratns beloning to currentUser Id
    this.restaurantsCollection = afs.collection<Restaurants>('restaurants'
      , ref => ref
        .where('ownerID', '==', this.userId));

    this.restaurants = this.restaurantsCollection.snapshotChanges().map(actions => {
      return actions.map(a => {
        const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Restaurants;
        const id = a.payload.doc.id;
        return { id, ...data };
      });
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

}
```

I am able to see the userId, when I use console.log within the authState function, but outside of it it is undefined.

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the order of execution.
Your query gets sent to server while userId is still undefined.
If you can nest your query inside of authStateChange handler - it should work as expected.

```
this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(user => {
  if (user) { this.userId = user.uid;
  console.log(this.userId);


// Query all restauratns beloning to currentUser Id
this.restaurantsCollection = afs.collection<Restaurants>('restaurants'
  , ref => ref
    .where('ownerID', '==', this.userId));

this.restaurants = this.restaurantsCollection.snapshotChanges().map(actions => {
  return actions.map(a => {
    const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Restaurants;
    const id = a.payload.doc.id;
    return { id, ...data };
  });
});
}
});
```